# ArcMap Error: Bad NBIT Argument

Tags: arcpy, error, arcgis-10.4

I keep getting "Fatal Error (GETMAP) Bad NBIT Argument" error for the following sample script:

```
fields = ['Value', 'Class_Name']
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(LuTable, fields)
for row in cursor:
    sqlQuery = "Value = " + str(row[0])
    print (sqlQuery)
    rasExtract = ExtractByAttributes(inRaster, sqlQuery)
    outCon = Con(IsNull(rasExtract),0,1)
    outAgg = Aggregate(outCon, 10, "SUM", "EXPAND", "DATA")
    outAgg.save(outRas)
del row, cursor
arcpy.Delete_management(LuTable)
```

I cannot find much documentation on this error. I have checked all the input rasters, output paths and set workspace and scratch space manually not included in the script. After inspecting it step-by-step, the `extract by attribute` tool creates a blank raster and then abruptly stops. The only reference I found is [this](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000001763) but they are talking about features not rasters. Has anyone experienced this error message?

Comment: Is it possible that your look up table has a value in it that does not exist in the raster you are extracting from? Are some rasters created or does it fail on the first attempt in the loop?

Comment: I checked it contains 16 categories and all them are present in the raster I am extracting from. It fails after initiating first raster. The result is a blank raster in the scratch directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly an answer, but recreating the data and re-running it resolved the issue. Also, I suggest rechecking raster environments.